# Can Moq ignore how many parameters passed to a funcion?

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to Moq my Generic Repository. I have a Method called SingleOrDefaultIncluding that looks like this:

```
T SingleOrDefaultIncluding(Expression<Func<T, bool>> wherePredicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);
```

Now in my unit test I set up Moq like this:

```
 _agreementRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.SingleOrDefaultIncluding
                                                (
                                                    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Agreement, bool>>>(),
                                                    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Agreement, object>>>(),
                                                    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Agreement, object>>>()
                                                )
            ).Returns(AgreementMocks.GetOne());
```

Can I somehow specify that whatever parameters passed to SingleOrDefaultIncluding it should return my Agreement? To make this work I must be sure to pass exactly 3 parameters as in the method I'm testing. Or Can I pass the Array to Moq somehow?

Comment: Sorry, my answer may be wrong. Do you intend to setup only when the array has length 2? My answer (as it stands) attempts to setup _all_ calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use the form where you don't "expand" the `params`? Something like:

```
_agreementRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.SingleOrDefaultIncluding
  (
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Agreement, bool>>>(),
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Agreement, object>>[]>()
  )
  ).Returns(AgreementMocks.GetOne());
```

Note the `[]` above. Untested.

In case I misunderstood, to freeze the number of parameters, maybe try:

```
_agreementRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.SingleOrDefaultIncluding
  (
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Agreement, bool>>>(),
    It.Is<Expression<Func<Agreement, object>>[]>(array => array.Length == 2)
  )
  ).Returns(AgreementMocks.GetOne());
```

using `It.Is<>` rather than `It.IsAny<>`.

Comment: I feel kind of stupid. I thought I tried that, but I must have gotten a bracket in the wrong Place. Works like a charm. Thank you!